# Separate each item in loop with a comma

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which creates a li tag for each item in the loop:

```
selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
        // create list for summary
        var selectionItemTag = document.createElement("li");
        selectionItemTag.innerHTML = selectionItem.textContent;
        summaryWidgetList.appendChild(selectionItemTag);

}
```

I have changed my ul tag to a div, and I don't want it to append a "li" tag anymore, I just want to create a list separated by commas, for example: "item1, item2, item3" etc.

I'm not sure how to change this code to do that instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that ?

```
var commaList = [...selectionList].map(el=>el.textContent).join(',')
```

If you want to group anything...:

```js
const selectionList     = document.querySelectorAll('#some-items > span')
  ,   summaryWidgetList = document.getElementById('summary-Widget-List')
  ;
var commaList = [...selectionList].map(el=>
  {
  let LI_elm         = document.createElement("li")
  LI_elm.textContent = el.textContent
  summaryWidgetList.appendChild(LI_elm)
  return el.textContent
  }
  ).join(',')


console.log(' commaList =' ,commaList )
```

```css
#some-items { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="some-items">
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item2</span>
  <span>item3</span>
</div>

<ul id="summary-Widget-List"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help, the options you gave me worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div element is the summaryWidgetList you mentioned in your code snippet, I suggest:

```
summaryWidgetList.innerText = selectionList.map(selectionItem => selectionItem.textContent).join(', ');
```

The map function will turn your array of objects with a textContent property into an array of strings. The join function will join the array of strings with the given separator.